# App Published But Displayed as Beta

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app on Google Play. The app went through alpha and beta stages, then was promoted to "published". Nonetheless, Google Play shows the app with the title **OpenApp (Beta)**. Why would this be?
Location on Google play [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ksdagile.openapp).

Comment: can you add screenshot ?

Comment: Looks like some caching at your end, it is not showing to me

Comment: It seems you are right, @TGMCians.

Comment: It not showing beta version at my end when I opned link peovided by you.

Comment: This is happening for me as well. @AharonManne, did you ever figure out if it was just a caching issue for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Google Play shows the app with the title OpenApp (Beta). Why would this be?

It looks like there is some caching issue at your end. Try it on some other machine or clear your browser cache then give a try.